# Share enum in Graphql

Tags: typescript, enums, graphql, apollo, express-graphql

Just started learning GraphQL and I would like to share an enum that I exported in a express apollo server.

```
./src/shared/fruitsEnum.ts

export enum fruitsEnum{
    APPLE,
    ORANGE
}
```

Import the enum

```
./src/market/fruits.ts

import { fruitsEnum } from "./src/shared/fruitsEnum.ts"

export const typeDef = `
    type Fruit{
        id: ID
        fruitName: fruitsEnum
    }

    type Query{
    ...
    }
`
```

I tried doing this but I am getting `Error: Unknown type fruitsEnum`. The reason that I put the enum in a separate location is because the same enum might be used at other schema. My goal is to have a shareable enum type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Typescript enum != graphQL enum

Enum needs to be defined in graphQL 'context' as in [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#enums), so it will work this way:

```
export const typeDef = `

  enum fruitsEnum{
    APPLE,
    ORANGE
  }

  type Fruit{
    id: ID
    fruitName: fruitsEnum
  }

  type Query{
  ...
  }
```

You can use `type-graphql` to 'connect' them (typescript and graphql contexts) and (share between client and server) **without explicit** [typescript defined] **enum definition inside** `typDef`.

More info [here](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/master/docs/enums.md)

Comment: Thanks. Let say if i don't use `type-graphql`, I have another file called `restaurant.ts` that will be using the same enum. I will be pasting the enum in the restaurant's schema from `fruits.ts` and of course without using the above package I will need to define the enum in the `fruits.ts's` schema. If I go this route, I will have 2 same enum defined at 2 different schemas

Comment: this is not a schema definition - ts enum has to be defined in the same shape in graphql, it's not imported/passed/compiled in ... see update

Comment: `it's not imported/passed/compiled in `, got it. Thank you again.